# PHPExcel code wont execute after submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpexcel

I would like help with my code because it can't be executed after I click the submit button(execute) to execute my PHPExcel code.

Instead it will only refresh the page and it doesn't generate Excel report, nothing happens. Can anyone help me to solve it please.

My current code:

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['execute'])){
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cant connect!");
        mysql_select_db("klayton") or die("cant find database!");
        require_once '../Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';
        $filename = 'final_worksheet.xlsx';

        $title = 'title';

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);


        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            $result = array();
for ( $n = 1; $n <=10; $n++ )
{
    $aic = isset($_POST['aic'.$n]) ? $_POST['aic'.$n] : "";
    $name = isset($_POST['name'.$n]) ? $_POST['name'.$n] : "";
    $optA = isset($_POST['optA'.$n]) ? $_POST['optA'.$n] : "";
    $optB = isset($_POST['optB'.$n]) ? $_POST['optB'.$n] : "";
    $optC = isset($_POST['optC'.$n]) ? $_POST['optC'.$n] : "";
    $optD = isset($_POST['optD'.$n]) ? $_POST['optD'.$n] : "";
    $other_qual = isset($_POST['other_qual'.$n]) ? $_POST['other_qual'.$n] : "";
    $interview = isset($_POST['interview'.$n]) ? $_POST['interview'.$n] : "";
    $total = isset($_POST['total'.$n]) ? $_POST['total'.$n] : "";
    $remarks = 'N/A';

    $result[] = array(
        $aic,
        $name,
        $optA,
        $optB,
        $optC,
        $optD,
        $other_qual,
        $interview,
        $total,
        $remarks );
}



        $headings = array(array('PNP-NUP FINAL WORKSHEET'),array(
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL),array(
            'AIC',
            'Name of Candidates',
            'Educational Attainment',
            'Experience',
            'In-Service Trainings & Seminars Attended',
            'Eligibility',
            'Other Qualifications',
            'Interview',
            'Total',
            'Remarks')
        );
        $fone = "___________________________";
        $ftwo = "Signature of Rater";
        $footer = array(array($fone),array($ftwo));

        $points = array(
            ' ',
            ' ',
            '(20 pts)',
            '(20 pts)',
            '(20 pts)',
            '(20 pts)',
            '(10 pts)',
            '(10 pts)',
            '(100 pts)',
            ' '
        );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
             ->getStyle('A1:J19')
             ->getAlignment()
             ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
          ->getBorders()
          ->getTop()
          ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK);
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
          ->getBorders()
          ->getBottom()
          ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK);
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
          ->getBorders()
          ->getLeft()
          ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK);
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
          ->getBorders()
          ->getRight()
          ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->getFont()->setSize(22);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:I2');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A16:I16')->getFont()->setSize(17);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A17:I17')->getFont()->setSize(13);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A16:I16');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A17:I17');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:I3')->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => true
                ),
                'alignment' => array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                ),
                'borders' => array(
                    'top' => array(
                        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                    )
                ),
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                    'rotation' => 90,
                    'startcolor' => array(
                        'argb' => 'FFA0A0A0'
                    ),
                    'endcolor' => array(
                        'argb' => 'FFFFFFFF'
                    )
                )
            )
    );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headings, null, 'A1');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($footer, null, 'A16');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($points, null, 'A4');
        $row = 5;
        foreach($result as $rows){
        if (!empty($rows[4])) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row);
            $row++;
        }
    }


    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="%s.xlsx"',preg_replace('/\\r\\n?|\\n/', '', $title)));
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}?>
```

html code:

```
<form>
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td width="28%"><b><font color="#000000">&nbsp;Batch #: </font><font color="#993300"><label id="batchcode" class="empty_batchcode"></label></font></b></td>
        <td width="45%" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td width="27%" rowspan="2">
        <br />
            <p><center><font size="+2" color="#990033"><b>Time:</b> <label id="startTime"></label></font></center></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="70%" ><input type="text" name="search" id="query" placeholder="search for batchcode here!" /></td>
<td width="3%" ><input id="send_search_form" type="button" value="Go" name="search" width="100%" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><hr></p>
<Font color="#000000"> 
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<p>
<center>
<a href="../logout.php" id="logout" class="right"><b>LOG-OUT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></a>
    <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PNP-NUP FINAL WORKSHEET</h1>
    </center></p>
<table border="1" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <th width="12%" rowspan="3">Name of Candidates</th>
        <th colspan="4">Minimum Requirements</th>
        <th width="12%" rowspan="2">Other Qualifications</th>
        <th width="9%" rowspan="2">Interview</th>
        <th width="8%" rowspan="2">Total</th>
        <th width="9%" rowspan="3">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="14%">Educational Attainment</th>
        <th width="10%">Experience</th>
        <th width="17%">In-Service Trainings & Seminars Attended</th>
        <th width="9%">Eligibility</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center>(20 pts)</center></td>
        <td><center>(20 pts)</center></td>
        <td><center>(20 pts)</center></td>
        <td><center>(20 pts)</center></td>
        <td><center>(10 pts)</center></td>
        <td><center>(10 pts)</center></td>
        <td><center>(100 pts)</center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <!--opt1-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id1" id="id1" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name1" id="name1" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA1" id="optA1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal1()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB1" id="optB1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal1()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC1" id="optC1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal1()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD1" id="optD1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal1()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual1" id="other_qual1" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview1" id="interview1" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total1" id="total1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal1()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks1" id="remarks1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt2-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id2" id="id2" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name2" id="name2" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA2" id="optA2" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal2()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB2" id="optB2" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal2()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC2" id="optC2" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal2()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD2" id="optD2" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal1()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual2" id="other_qual2" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview2" id="interview2" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total2" id="total2" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal2()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks2" id="remarks2" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt3-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id3" id="id3" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name3" id="name3" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA3" id="optA3" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal3()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB3" id="optB3" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal3()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC3" id="optC3" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal3()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD3" id="optD3" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal3()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual3" id="other_qual3" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview3" id="interview3" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total3" id="total3" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal3()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks3" id="remarks3" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt4-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id4" id="id4" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name4" id="name4" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA4" id="optA4" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal4()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB4" id="optB4" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal4()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC4" id="optC4" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal4()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD4" id="optD4" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal4()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual4" id="other_qual4" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview4" id="interview4" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total4" id="total4" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal4()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks4" id="remarks4" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt5-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id5" id="id5" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name5" id="name5" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA5" id="optA5" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal5()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB5" id="optB5" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal5()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC5" id="optC5" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal5()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD5" id="optD5" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal5()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual5" id="other_qual5" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview5" id="interview5" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total5" id="total5" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal5()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks5" id="remarks5" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt6-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id6" id="id6" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name6" id="name6" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA6" id="optA6" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal6()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB6" id="optB6" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal6()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC6" id="optC6" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal6()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD6" id="optD6" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal6()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual6" id="other_qual6" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview6" id="interview6" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total6" id="total6" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal6()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks6" id="remarks6" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt7-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id7" id="id7" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name7" id="name7" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA7" id="optA7" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal7()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB7" id="optB7" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal7()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC7" id="optC7" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal7()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD7" id="optD7" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal7()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual7" id="other_qual7" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview7" id="interview7" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total7" id="total7" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal7()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks7" id="remarks7" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt8-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id8" id="id8" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name8" id="name8" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA8" id="optA8" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal8()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB8" id="optB8" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal8()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC8" id="optC8" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal8()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD8" id="optD8" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal8()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual8" id="other_qual8" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview8" id="interview8" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total8" id="total8" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal8()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks8" id="remarks8" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt9-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id9" id="id9" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name9" id="name9" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA9" id="optA9" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal9()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB9" id="optB9" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal9()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC9" id="optC9" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal9()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD9" id="optD9" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal9()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual9" id="other_qual9" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview9" id="interview9" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total9" id="total9" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal9()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks9" id="remarks9" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <!--opt10-->
    <input class="search_form_input" type="hidden" name="id10" id="id10" readonly /> 
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="name10" id="name10" readonly type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optA10" id="optA10" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal10()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optB10" id="optB10" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal10()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optC10" id="optC10" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal10()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="optD10" id="optD10" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal10()" maxlength="2" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="other_qual10" id="other_qual10" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" readonly name="interview10" id="interview10" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="total10" id="total10" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text" onKeyUp="optTotal10()" /></td>
    <td><input class="search_form_input" name="remarks10" id="remarks10" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" readonly type="text"></td>
    </tr>
   <!--fetch table starts here-->
   <!--fetch table ends here-->
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="repcode" id="repcode" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['repcode']; ?>" />
</font>
<input type="submit" name="execute" id="execute" value="Send to Excel" style="width:123px;height:30px" formnovalidate /><input type="submit" style="width:849px;height:30px" value="CLICK ME TO UPDATE" name="updates" id="updates" formnovalidate disabled />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't just paste all of your code like that. Isolate the parts of code you have problems with and explain what you want.

Comment: have you ever thought about the concept of indexes in arrays?

Comment: "nothing happens" Are you sure? Is error reporting on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard is `GET`, so  `if(isset($_POST['execute'])){` is always false, and not executing 
anything. Change:

```
<form method="POST">
     <table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, much typing, try this:

```
...
$result = array();
for ( $n = 1; $n <=10; $n++ )
{
    $aic = isset($_POST['aic'.$n]) ? $_POST['aic'.$n] : "";
    $name = isset($_POST['name'.$n]) ? $_POST['name'.$n] : "";
    $optA = isset($_POST['optA'.$n]) ? $_POST['optA'.$n] : "";
    $optB = isset($_POST['optB'.$n]) ? $_POST['optB'.$n] : "";
    $optC = isset($_POST['optC'.$n]) ? $_POST['optC'.$n] : "";
    $optD = isset($_POST['optD'.$n]) ? $_POST['optD'.$n] : "";
    $other_qual = isset($_POST['other_qual'.$n]) ? $_POST['other_qual'.$n] : "";
    $interview = isset($_POST['interview'.$n]) ? $_POST['interview'.$n] : "";
    $total = isset($_POST['total'.$n]) ? $_POST['total'.$n] : "";
    $remarks = 'N/A';

    $result[] = array(
        $aic,
        $name,
        $optA,
        $optB,
        $optC,
        $optD,
        $other_qual,
        $interview,
        $total,
        $remarks );
}
...
```

Comment: do you know whats the cause my code not working? if i click the submit button it will only refresh the page and nothing happens.

Comment: there is no submit button in your code, how can we tell?